# How_to_solve_python_version_problem_networkx?

Tags: version-control, typeerror, networkx

Type:
if you having problem with networkx library in python, you should follow the below step by step :
1-)python --version

2-)if the version is 3.7, you need to downgrade version

3-)conda install python=3.6

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question.

Comment: Hi Resit,  welcome to stackoverflow.  Stackoverflow is intended to be a "question and answer" site.  Can you reframe this as a clear question?  At that point you could give your own answer (or others can provide theirs).  As it stands, it's a little unclear what the problem is that you're trying to solve here.

Comment: Hi @rexcfnghk, This is one of the often asked question thats why I posted it.